# Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

This is the problem that I'm having trouble on:

Let $a$ and $b$ be natural numbers with $1000000>a>b$. What bound does Theorem 4.2.3 give for the number of steps the Euclidean Algorithm will take when performed on $a$ and $b$?

Theorem 4.2.3 states "for any pair of natural numbers $a$ and $b$, the Euclidean Algorithm takes at most $\log_2(ab)$ steps to find $\gcd (a,b)$.

Would it be $\log_2(10^6\cdot10^6)=\log_2(12)$?

Comment: The left side is right, the right side is not right.  The bound is $\log_2(10^{12})$, which is $12\log_2(10)$.

Comment: So mine would be about 39 steps or should I round to 40 since the number is 39.84?

Comment: Since $a$ and $b$ are less than $ 1$ million, the upper bound $ B$ will be less than $12 \log_2 10. $ Since $\log_{10}2=0.30103...$ we have  $B<36$  so $B$ is at most $35$.

Comment: At most $39.84$, since the number of steps is an integer, means at most $39$.

Comment: @user254665 Why are you using log base 10 if the theorem says log base 2?

Comment: $12 \log_2 10=12/ \log_{10}2=12/0.30103...$  I know $\log_{10}2$  from memory.

Comment: @user254665 So how did you get 35 then?

Comment: $35< \log_2(10^6-1)(10^6-2)<12\log_2 10<36$. I dk whether 35 is the least upper bound for a, b less than 1 million  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically the answer is $log_2((10^6-1)(10^6-2))$ (due to the strict inequalities) but you get the same result. Calculating it out should give you

$$39 < log_2((10^6-1)(10^6-2)) <40.$$

The largest integer value would then be 39.

Comment: When I calculated $log_2((10^6-1)(10^6-2))$ I got ~ 3.32 and not 39.

Comment: $8<2^{3.32}< 16<<(10^6-1)(10^6-2)$. If you are trying to convert to base $10$ make sure you use $log_{2}(x)=\frac{log_{10}(x)}{log_{10}(2)}$

Comment: @ematth7, I believe you multiplied by $log_{10}(2)$ when you should have divided. That would give you the answer you got.